# AngularJS - headlines news display like CNN channel bottom area new feeds

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs, and I need to display headlines news like CNN channel bottom area news feeds

I got the feed from CNN and have it in a $scope variable,
How can I display each feed - make it to stay on the screen for 10 sec
and move out the current one and bring in the next one,

I cannot use "ng-repeat" as it display all the items in the array object ;
in my case I need to display one after another.

I tried using custom directive link function but unable to access news feed object inside link function

```
app.controller('tickerController', function($http, $scope, FeedService) {
  function loadNewsFeed() {
    FeedService.parseFeed(url).then(function(res) {                 
      $scope.newsFeedObject = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;                           
    });
  }

  app.directive('currentNews',function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              element.html(scope.newsFeedObject[0].title); //Error line
            }
    };
  }
```

at `//Error line` compiler says '0' is not recognized, but was able to access this outside link function

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods I know of depending on what you're trying to do (you could also combine them).

The first is to paginate the feed and then have angular update the "page" that the feed is on every 10 seconds

The second is to place the first feed on the screen in a div. Then create a second "loading" div off-screen with the next feed. Use the animations in JQuery to slide on div off the screen and the other onto it. Then change the data in the original div to that of the "loading" div and have the divs snap back into place. then prepare the "loading" div with the next feed